# c# code in xamarin.android is not executed

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have this code that I wrote in order to create a pdf that allows Arabic words in it. what happened is that the code execution returned nothing. I mean nothing happened. no toast appeared, no pdf was created, but still got no errors, no exceptions, nothing at all.
this is the code:

```
    Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            btn.Click += delegate 
            {
                btn.Text = "okay";
                 Toast.MakeText(this, "start", ToastLength.Long);
            var path2 = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2.ToString(), "myfile4.pdf");
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            PdfDocument pdf2 = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document2 = new Document(pdf2, PageSize.A4);
            AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
            string content;
            Stream stream2 = assets.Open("ARIAL.TTF");
            var memorystrm = new MemoryStream();
            stream2.CopyTo(memorystrm);
            byte[] t = memorystrm.ToArray();
            Toast.MakeText(this, t.Length.ToString(), ToastLength.Long);
            if (t != null)
            {
                PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(t, "UTF-8", true);
                document2.SetFont(russian);
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello World! ")
                    .Add(new Text("صباح! ").SetFontSize(14)).Add(new Text("Bonjour le monde! ").SetFontSize(10));
                document2.Add(p);
                document2.Close();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "error", ToastLength.Long);
            }


            };
```

I added `btn.Text="okay";` to check if it works. it did, but the code afterwards wasn't executed. why is that?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

> I mean nothing happened. no toast appeared

You forgot to call Show() method;

```
Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

**Second**,did you forget to request **runtime permissions** ?

I test with a simple sample like below and it works well:

```
button.Click += Click_Event;

private void Click_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            button.Text = "okay";
            Toast.MakeText(this, "start", ToastLength.Long);
            var path2 = global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);// my pdf file is in the Downloads folder.
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2.ToString(), "pdf.pdf");
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            PdfDocument pdf2 = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document2 = new Document(pdf2, PageSize.A4);
            AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
            string content;
            Stream stream2 = assets.Open("arial.ttf");
            var memorystrm = new MemoryStream();
            stream2.CopyTo(memorystrm);
            byte[] t = memorystrm.ToArray();
            Toast.MakeText(this, t.Length.ToString(), ToastLength.Long);
            if (t != null)
            {
                PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(t, "UTF-8", true);
                document2.SetFont(russian);
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello World! ")
                    .Add(new Text("صباح! ").SetFontSize(14)).Add(new Text("Bonjour le monde! ").SetFontSize(10));
                document2.Add(p);
                document2.Close();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "error", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
        }
    }
```

the effect like this:

[image]

Comment: oh my GOD! how did I forget the .Show(). I had all my mind focused on the pdf font that I couldn't see what the issue was. but one problem is that the Arabic word didn't appear, is it that Arial font doesn't support Arabic letters?